# Spring Controller on HTTPS and HTTP

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, controller

Can I make a controller is available by http and https.

Example:

https://mysite.ru/cart - one controller one page

http://mysite.ru/cart - same controller same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers merely process a request and return the response. You may choose to use different controllers to process different URL patters but none of these are in anyway related to the protocol used.

Protocol use would depend how you deploy your server. If you support `SSL` i.e provide server with valid `keystore certificate` and `password` then you will be able to use https protocol in your URLs.

Controllers deal with requests depending on the URL patters  that comes after the protocol.

For supporting https URLs you can refer to my blog post on -[Supporting https URLs on your server](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2014/06/supporting-https-urlson-your-server.html).

Answer (score 2):

Your Spring controller is independent of protocol scheme (HTTPS/HTTP). Rather your application server (Servlet Container) take care of this Https/Http.

Answer (score 0):

Spring security!

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/address/**" requires-channel="any" />
```